# Group array through value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this

Array
   (

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => 123
        [id] => 105740727
        [email] =>fghfhfh
        [phrases_relevant] => 123
        [searches_id] => 105740727
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => porshe
        [id] => 105713889
        [email] => fghfghf
        [phrases_relevant] => porshe
        [searches_id] => 105713889
    )

 [3] => Array
    (
        [name] => porshe
        [id] => 105713889
        [email] => fghfghf
        [phrases_relevant] => merce
        [searches_id] => 105713889
    )
```

I need group this group via value. Output array should looks like below.  dimension second and third has same searches_id

```
  [0] => Array
    (
        [email] => fghfghf
        [projects]=>
              [porshe] => [porshe, merce]
  [1] => ...
```

edit;

my tried;

```
    foreach ($results as $key => $result) {
         $testArray[]['projects'][$result['name']][] = $result['phrases_relevant'];
```

but this insert one phrases;

Comment: Please post the code you have tried

Comment: Why is `phrases_relevant` value `123` missing in your output? Your output example is very incomplete. Could you complete it for the given input?

Comment: it is onlny example, value phrases does not matter

Comment: Examples always matter in questions, but I think I know what you want. You want to group the array entries on `searches_id`. So the columns `name`, `id`, `email` and `phrases_relevant` can all vary when the `searches_id` is the same? Or does only the `phrases_relevant` vary, as in your example?

Comment: if we will group searches id, email will be same everywhere. Name it is always first element phrases_relevant, so it connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to sort first by `searches_id` then apply loop,

```
function sortByOrder($a, $b)
{
    return $a['searches_id'] - $b['searches_id'];
}
usort($myArray, 'sortByOrder');
foreach ($myArray as $key => $value) {
    $result[$value['searches_id']]['email']      = $value['email'];
    $result[$value['searches_id']]['projects'][] = $value['phrases_relevant'];
}
$result = array_values($result); // reset keys used for array generation
```

Working [demo](https://3v4l.org/J7eGX).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `foreach`

```
$res = [];
foreach($arr as $key => $value){

array_key_exists($value['id'], $res) ?
    ($res[$value['id']]['phrases_relevant'] = $res[$value['id']]['phrases_relevant'].','.$value['phrases_relevant'])
:
($res[$value['id']] = ['email' => $value['email'],'phrases_relevant' => $value['phrases_relevant']]);
}
print_r(array_values($res))
```

[Live Demo](https://3v4l.org/MMbiS)

Comment: Using a ternary operator instead of the far more appropriate if/else makes this code almost impossible to understand.